# localStorage.getItem ('token') returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `Items` component I set the toke in localstorage. The `Details` component tries to access this token. It gets `null`

```
class Items extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

  }

  getT = () => {

    axios({ 
      method: 'post', 
      url: '/oauth2/token', 
      data, 
      config
    }) 
      .then(res => { 
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log(res.data)
          this.setState({
            token: res.data
          })
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data['access_token']))
        } else {
          const error = new Error(res.error);
          throw error;
        }
      }).catch(err => { 
        console.error(err);
        alert('Error logging in please try again'); 
      });

  }

  render () {

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="instancesUl">
                {   this.props.items.map((item, index) => 
                      <li 

                        key={item.id}
                        item={item}
                        onClick = {this.getT}
                      >
                      </li>
                    )
                }          
            </ul>
            <Details

            />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
class Details extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token');

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
            url: `https://app`,
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(res => {

        })
        .catch(error => {

        }) 
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div >

      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: When is the getT method called to set the local storage value?

Comment: Are you certain that the localStorage read happens **after** the write?

Comment: Not much debugging information given here

Comment: @Harikrishnan When I click <li></li> call function getT()

Comment: Details constructor is called before the token set, after your token is set the constructor of Details won't be invoked again so the old value their remains

Comment: @idmitrov  You have right. What solution do you suggest?

Comment: First of all the best place/moment to set your token is on login() i.e before any other action like get items/books/stuff.

In your case just simply don't use the constructor, you have many ways, one of which is to pass the token via props so you will have always the updated value.

Again you should set your token on first login, not in action for getting Items or whatever.

Comment: @idmitrov But I have a bit of a difficult task. First I log in, then I select instances and a token is generated when the instance is selected.

Comment: @idmitrov Items is the place to choose an instance

Comment: @Umbro simply pass your Items token to Details as a prop.

i.e Details must use this.props.token and in your Items class render method you need <Details token={this.state.token} />

I am out and cannot write you an example right now but I am sure that you could manage to solve it on your own.

Comment: @idmitrov I understand. But I create a chrome extension written in React. Like this closed window, this.props.token is destroyed. I need a token saved in local.storage. As I open the window, do not log in again. I have to take token with local.storage

Comment: Okay this is what I am talking about: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-meninsky-27ibg?fontsize=14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196988/discussion-between-umbro-and-idmitrov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **Details constructor** is invoked earlier at the time when the localStorage is empty, after that your logic to set the token works but Details constructor does not execute again to get the updated value.

[Here is an example how you could tweak your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-meninsky-27ibg?fontsize=14)

In short you should not rely on the state everywhere, init your state in a parent component and setState there, pass it properties to the children components via **React** **props**, so when you change the state your props will get updated also and force the component which they belong to render the update and call all needed logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading before the write.

**Root of Problem:**

- getT method of class Items is responsible for writing the
  localstorage and which has async call, It will take some time to get
  data from server so you don't know when it will return.
- Details component is rendered inside the Items component so it will
  be called immediately when it reaches the render method and as discussed in
  above point we are not sure token is written is localstorage or not.

**Solution:**

- You can set some value in state saying token_is_saved
- You can render Details component only when token_is_saved is true

Initialize state in Items constructor,

```
this.state = { 
   token: null
}
```

Modify your Items's render method as,

```
{
    this.state.token && <Details />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Constructor of Details component works once in the very beginning while instantiating the component class and in that case there would be not token available in the localStorage. After if you click on the button, which later makes the call to the server and after promise is being resolved, you store the token. After refreshing your page, it will become available for you.

Comment: And if I removed the `Details` component from` Items`. Did you redirect from 'Items' to 'Details' token will be available?

Answer (score -1):

Is this the correct way of implementation?

```
import Vue from 'vue';    
import axios from 'axios';    
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1";    
const token  = localStorage.getItem('token');    
export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ${token}'    
    }
});
```